# How to use VTA algorithm to create call graph with soot and spark for java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, analysis, soot

I'm new in analysis with **soot** framework and now I need to implement the **VTA algorithm** and use it to create call graphs.

How can I implement **VTA**?

and how can I use **VTA** implementation in soot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might do not need it anymore, but Soot provides a simple way to create call graphs. You can use the command line or the provided API.

You can set different settings, ones that are realted to call graphs are
[CG phase options in Soot](https://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/tutorial/phase/phase.html#SECTION00060000000000000000). The texts in parenthesis are the names and values for a given phase.

When using API (You need the Soot jar, You can get it from [Soot Github repo](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot/)) you set the options by method calls like

```
Options.v().setPhaseOption("cg","enabled:true");
```

After setting everything You need You should run Soot with the needed arguments

```
soot.Main.main(args);
```

After that You can get the CallGraph

```
CallGraph cg = Scene.v().getCallGraph();
```

After that You just write a simple method that traverses the graph and serialize it.